# Java SQL, General error org.hsqldb.HsqlException

Tags: java, sql

I'm working on Java and use Access (SQL) database.
I want to insert into a table as you can see:

```java
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("INSERT INTO Mybooks (category,book_id) VALUES ('" + variable  + "'," + 64) + ")");
```

However, a strange error comes:

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: General error
```

Comment: That example code cannot work, please have a look at the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `executeUpdate` for database write operations

```java
PreparedStatement insertStatement = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Mybooks (category,book_id) VALUES (?, ?)"); // no SQL injection here!
insertStatement.setString(1, variable);
insertStatement.setInt(2, 64);
insertStatement.executeUpdate();
```